# How to convert smallestWidth pixels to Android smallestWidth in dp

Tags: android

I have 7" tablet with resolution of 600*1024. I observations of this device are,

- Diagonal resolution=169 dpi
- Diagonal resolution=113 dp
- Android Resolution bucket = HDPI
- Width * Height = 400 dp * 682 dp
- Smallest Width = 400 dp

But if i use `config.smallestScreenWidthDp` it returns smallestWidth is 600 dp. But i got 400 dp. How to calculate this 600 px to dp?

**My Calculation:**

Device actual smallest width = `600 px`

Device is HDPI. So divide the px value by MDPI scaling factor `1.50`.

I got answer as `600/1.5= 400 dp`